# PullToRefreshListView is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm planning to use PullToRefreshListView, but found it's deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. MS suggest to use the RefreshContainer available in the 1803 version of Windows.

So questions comes:

1. Not all windows are 1803 or above, many are still 10240 or 15063, etc.
2. RefreshContainer only exists on 1803 or above.
3. Suppose PullToRefreshListView will be removed on 1810, Which one I should use 
   to make sure the controls suite to both >=1810 and <1810?

Microsoft API update does not consider developers' feelings at all. No wonder many developers left.

[image]

Comment: Note that this is a feature of the Windows Community Toolkit, which is something you include in your application. Windows never shipped a `PullToRefreshListView` control, and nothing is being removed from Windows. As the answer from @rjobidon below states, you can ship this version of the toolkit in your app forever if you want, and the feature will never disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still continue using the PullToRefreshListView by using the source directly, but Microsoft will remove it from the nuget packages in the future and will not fix bugs.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/1946#issuecomment-403322810